# ngx-translate access json file in different port

Tags: angular5, ngx-translate

I am using ngx-translate for translating content in my angular app. But this is running in different port ( for example: 8090). I have done setup referring translatehttploader by referring https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate

once I build and serve the app, it is throwing error as the json file not found ( Error 404). 
The url it displays as

```
http://localhost/assets/i18n/en.json
```

if I add the port in the url (i.e.)

```
http:8090//localhost/assets/i18n/en.json
```

I am able to see the json content in browser. What I infer that it is referring default port 80. But it should refer the port 8090.  So Can some one help me where I should configure the port to read json file by app to make translatehttploader serve from it?

Comment: Are you running your app on port 80 and your translation file (en.json) is hosted at port 8090?

Comment: No. My app is running on 8090 port but it has a parent app which is running in default port.  In angular-cli.json file, the port has been configured to serve from 8090. So, ideally this should take care the json file also. Not sure, why it is defaulting to 80 port

Comment: Finally, I achieved this by hosting the files in iis application which is running in port 80 (parent app) and it worked.